Proof of existence of optimal policy
I have been trying to prove existence of an optimal policy for RL. I have proved that the Bellman optimality operator, $B: \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{S}|} \to \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{S}|}$ given by
$$B(v_\pi)(\; \cdot\; ) = \max_{a \in \mathcal{A}(\; \cdot \;)} \sum_{r \in \mathcal{R}} \sum_{s' \in \mathcal{S}} p(s', r|\;\cdot\; , a) \big[ r + \gamma v_\pi(s') \big]$$
Is a contraction under the infinity norm. As per usual $\mathcal{S}$ and $\mathcal{A}$ denotes the state and action spaces respectively.
Here is where I am a bit confused. We know that $B$ must have a unique fixed point, by Banach fixed point theorem. We also know that if an optimal policy exist its state value, $v^*$, must be the unique fixed point, since $B(v^*) = v^*$. Is this sufficient to conclude that an optimal policy must existence?
Edit:
Would the following reasoning be correct?
By the Banach fixed-point theorem, $v^*$ is unique and the sequence $\{v_{\pi_n}\}_{n=0}^\infty$ defined by $v_{\pi_{n+1}} = B(v_{\pi_{n}})$ converges to $v^*$ for any initial state-value function $v_0 \in \mathbb{R}^{|\mathcal{S}|}$. In particular $\pi_n \overset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}\pi^*$.

There's still some missing link since from what you described above we merely know that $v^*$ is the unique solution to the BOE with Bellman optimality operator. Whether it is the optimal state value of some existent policy $\pi^*$ is still unclear, thus we need to show $v^∗$ is the optimal state value of a constructed policy $\pi^*$ which is then an optimal policy and may not be unique at all.

I understand.. Can I construct policy $\pi^$ by $$\pi^(s) = \text{argmax}a \sum{r \in \mathcal{R}} \sum_{s' \in \mathcal{S}} p(s', r|;\cdot; , a) \big[ r + \gamma v^*(s') \big]$$

@mNugget sounds good to me since the optimal policy here must attain probability 1 for a best action in DP.
